# Regular Expression for Azure SQL Database server administrator login password. Can this be improved?

Tags: sql-server, regex, azure, azure-sql-database

I've tried to write a regular expression for validating administrator login password complexity for Azure SQL Database server. Based on the documentation [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms161959.aspx):

[image]

and with the help of this [`link`](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Password-Policy-using-Regular-Expressions-and-ASPNet-RegularExpression-Validator.aspx), I have come up with following pattern to validate the password complexity:

```
^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\{\[\}\]\|\\\:\;\"\'\<\,\>\.\?\/])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\{\[\}\]\|\\\:\;\"\'\<\,\>\.\?\/])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\{\[\}\]\|\\\:\;\"\'\<\,\>\.\?\/])(?=.*[A-Z]))[a-zA-Z\d\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\{\[\}\]\|\\\:\;\"\'\<\,\>\.\?\/]{8,128}$
```

This one obviously doesn't deal with the 1st scenario (password does not contain the account name of the user) but all other things are covered and based on my testing it works.

However I am curious to know if this can be improved somehow. One thing I am thinking is that I can remove literal character (`\`) for some of the non-alphanumeric characters.

Any other things I can do to improve this pattern?

Comment: You are right.  There are way more escape sequences than necessary.  That's especially true in the character classes (i.e. between the square brackets) since the only characters which need to be escaped in a character class are these three: `\-]`.

Comment: The characters that must be escaped inside a character class vary from flavor to flavor. To play it safe, escape ONLY `[`, `]`, `^`, `-`, ``\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few thing you can do:

- Remove useless escaping within brackets:

  ```
  [~`!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/]
  ```
- introduce a variable to avoid repetition on the previous group. If you want to allow in the future another special char it would be easier to change.
- change `a-zA-Z\d_` to `\w`.
- put it multi-line for readability (though I'm not sure that it's supported).

Which would give:

```
^(
  (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/])
 |(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/])
 |(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])
 |(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/])(?=.*[A-Z])
)
[\w~`!@#$%^&*()\-+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/]{8,128}$
```

*Note 1*: If by *Non-alphabetic characters* you meant *anything that is not a letter or a number*, switch to `\W`.

*Note 2*: As of now, your regex will not allow the user to use accentuated chars

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed helpful. Regarding Note 2: I am not sure if accentuated characters are even supported. Let me give it a try though.